# Problems with database after cloning Django app from Github

Tags: python, django, git, github

I have just cloned a Django app from Github to a local directory. I know for a fact that the app works because I've run it on others' computers.

When I run the server, I can see the site and register for an account. This works fine (I get a confirmation email). But then my login information causes an error because the DB appears to not have configured properly on my machine. I get the following errors:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in execute
                return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) ...
▶ Local vars
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in execute
        return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params) ...
▶ Local vars
The above exception (no such table: django_session) was the direct cause of the following exception:

(It then lists a bunch of problems with local vars).

I tried making migrations with every part of the app but this didn't appear to fix anything.

Comment: It might be a good idea to show some of the errors. Indent 4 spaces (or highlight and use the "{}" sign in the editor) for code.

A lot of things can go wrong when running an app from a git clone:
Wrong Python version, not having all the libraries/frameworks installed (which is why a requirements.txt  to`pip install` for Python projects on GitHub is important); unresolved references (such as environment/PATH variables that aren't in the same place on the new system). 
Running `make migrations` and `migrate` doesn't always cut it, either -- there are times when deleting the db file is needed.

Answer (score 0):

The django_sessions table should get initialized when you run your first migrations. You said taht you made your migrations, but did you run them (with `python manage.py migrate`). Also, do you have `django.contrib.auth` in the `installed_apps` in your settings file? This is the app that owns that session table